# Uso de geolocation e infowindow: Ionic Google Maps Markers

Tags: json, google-maps, ionic2

En una app utilizando Google Maps JavaScript API, requiero obtener los marcadores desde un archivo JSON, importando los plugins pertinentes encontré un tutorial que funciona, requiero hacer geolocalización, pero **no** permite usar *loadMap* sino **displayGoogleMap**, abajo dejo el código.

```
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('mapContainer') mapContainer: ElementRef;
  map: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.displayGoogleMap();
    this.getMarkers();
  }

  displayGoogleMap() {
    let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.8127004, 14.2106225);

    let mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapContainer.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  }

  getMarkers() {
    this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json')
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.addMarkersToMap(data);
    });
  }

  addMarkersToMap(markers) {
    for(let marker of markers) {
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
      var miMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: marker.title});
      miMarker.setMap(this.map);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: En el momento no me muestra error, quiero cambiar:  `let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.8127004, 14.2106225);` por la ubicación del usuario haciendo geolocalización

Answer (score 1):

Para eso debes instalar el plugin Cordova GeoLocation :

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-geolocation`

Y tambien el nativo

```
npm install --save @ionic-native/geolocation
```

La importacion en tu controlador

```
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation';
```

Y luego cuando dibujes el mapa :

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

donde `this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position)` obtiene la posicion actual del usuario

Dentro de tu codigo debes cambiar

```
getMarkers() {
    this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json')
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
         this.addMarker(data);
    });
}
```

Para agregar marcadores :

```
addInfoWindow(marker, content) {

    let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: content
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
        infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
    });

}

addMarker(markers) {
    for (let marker of markers) {
        let position = {marker.lat, marker.lng};
        let marker_custom = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: position
        });
        let content = marker.title;          

        this.addInfoWindow(marker_custom, content);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias @sioesi, seguí tus instrucciones y en efecto geolocaliza el dispositivo, pero no permite agregar marcadores, así debería quedar (http://vistarmm.com/data/get.png) y con tus instrucciones (http://vistarmm.com/data/this.png)

Comment: `getMarkers() {
    this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json')
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.addMarkersToMap(data);
    });
  }

  addMarkersToMap(markers) {
    for(let marker of markers) {
      var position = new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude);
      var miMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, title: marker.title});
      miMarker.setMap(this.map);
    }`

Comment: agrege codigo para el marker! @VladimirYankenCifuentes

Comment: originalmente mi código fuente (vistarmm.com/data/this.png):

Comment: @VladimirYankenCifuentes me referia a que modifique mi respuesta y te agregue el codigo para que agregues los marcadores

Comment: (http://vistarmm.com/data/error.png) . Segui este tutorial,
 ya que requiero descargar los marcadores desde una base de datos (https://www.christianengvall.se/ionic2-google-maps-markers/)

Comment: Y ahora como estas obteniendo tus markers? porque yo copie el for que le haces y reemplace el codigo pero nada mas :S

Comment: @VladimirYankenCifuentes volvi a editar mi respuesta, me faltaba cambiar el destino de la funcion `getMarkers`

Comment: `getMarkers() {
   this.http.get('assets/data/markers.json')
    .map((res) => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
    this.addMarkersToMap(data);
   });
  }`

Comment: @VladimirYankenCifuentes por favor mira mi respuesta, edite tu funcion getMarkers